# Solving $\frac{dy}{dx} = y - 3x$ with $y(-1) = 2$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, integrating-factor

Alright I know I'm asking for an answer with this, however on all of the examples presented to me with my notes in class and online, 
It doesn't show $y' = yx \leftarrow \textrm{example}$.

It shows problems like $y' + \tan(x)y = \cos^2(x)$. that's just an example. They have $y'$ on the left with $x$ and $y$.

Therefore, I am not certain that I will be making an error that I won't know about. I just want some example on how to do this so I don't mess up with some explanation.

Comment: What is $Y$? here integrating factor is $\exp(-x)$ and then try to solve.

Comment: @John I'm sorry, I'm confused, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is
$$y'-y=-3x$$
If we multiply both sides by
$$\mu = \exp\left(\int -1 \right)=\exp(-x)$$
We can rewrite it as
$$\left(\exp(-x)y\right)'=-3x\exp(-x)$$
Can you see why? Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

The integrating factor will work whenever you have $y'+f(x)y=g(x)$, $f$ and $g$ continuous.

Here $f(x)=-1$ and $g(x)=-3x$.

Thus use $e^{\int -1\operatorname{dx}}=e^{-x}$.

Get $(e^{-x}y)'=e^{-x}(-3x)$.

> Integrate:  $e^{-x}y=3(e^{-x}+xe^{-x})+C$
> Finally, $y=3(1+x)+Ce^x$.
> And $y(-1)=0+\frac Ce=2\implies C=2e$.
> So $y=3+3x+2e^{x+1}$.
>   Note:  Integration by parts was used.